# Baby leopard gecko hasn’t eaten

Tags: health, reptiles, eating, leopard-geckos, geckos

Hi I bought a baby leopard gecko almost two weeks ago, on 14th August, and I haven't seen him eat. He is a hatchling.  I offer him mealworms and Phoenix worms, but he has not ate since I got him. He is set up in a 10 gal (38 liters) tank with three hideouts: warm, cool and humid. The warm side is set at 90 degrees Fahrenheit (32 degrees Celsius). The day after I got him he shed and Sunday he shed again. He is pooping, so I don’t think it is impaction. He stays in his humid hideout most of the time, which is half on the warm side. I am really worried about him, what can I do to help him?

Comment: Welcome to Pets! I linked a similar question with several answers that sounds exactly like yours. If you think that it doesn't answer your question, please explain how your problem is different or what aspect of your question wasn't answered. In that case we can reopen your post.